# В чем причина  неработоспособности программы?

Tags: c

Можно бесконечно вводить числа, однако ничего не считает и не выводит на экран.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int _tmain()
{    
    Float a, b, c, d, m, n, f;

    printf("na=");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("nb=");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("nc=");
    scanf("%f", &c);
    printf("nd=");
    scanf("%f", &d);
    m = a * d;
    n = b * c;
    f = m + n;
    f = sqrt(f);
    printf("nm=%f", m);
    printf("nn=%f", n);
    printf("nn=%f", f);
    printf("nn=%f", sin(f));
    printf("nn=%f", cos(f));

    _getch();
}
```

Comment: Только что скомпилировал, убрав `#include "stdafx.h"`, `#include <math.h>`, `_getch();` и заменив `_tmain()` на `main()`. Все работает.

Comment: м... спасибо сча попробую..

Comment: нет.. не работаает все равно.. видимо саму си++ менять надо..

Comment: У вас точно значение `f`, передаваемое в `sqrt`, не отрицательное? И - добавьте-ка *при выводе* после `%f` - `\n`: типа `printf("nn=%f\n", f);` - некоторые очень любят вывод кэшировать...

Answer (score 1):

Упрощаем до одной переменной:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float f;

    printf("f=?\n");
    scanf("%f", &f);

    f = sqrt(f);

    printf("sqrt(f)=%f", f);

    return 0;
}
```

Все работает. [Доказательство](http://ideone.com/vGPEy).